# C read socket changes occasionally

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, fork

So I have a web server which forks into sub-processes which will handle multiple clients through a multi thread system.

There is one problem though. Some times, accept() returns Bad File Descriptor!
Using ab too test the web server, sometimes I get that error. So let's say the first 500 requests are processed fine but then, Bad File Descriptor - the socket fd seems like a real big integer suddenly (no longer a valid one).

I only close it once - at the end of the program so it doesn't make sense that it's suddenly getting closed - gdb breakpoints guarantee me that this is exiting properly.

I also have another issue though, which seems to be that a thread created by a child process exits "randomly". It's not random, I know but I can't find why it exists as nothing gets output to the screen. I'm saying it's "random" because helgrind tells me the exiting thread still has two locks holding (I have a mutex within a mutex (and need it) - I have also tried using one mutex only and the problem remains). Is there any possibility of something causing a thread to close?

I can provide the code but it's a bit extensive and it has comments in portuguese and variable/function names are in portuguese as well.

**UPDATE**

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
void *gere_processo(void*pst)
{
    process_struct pstruct = *(process_struct*)pst;

    int fork_id;
    int fd[2];

    if(pipe(fd)==-1)
    {
        perror("Erro a criar pipe: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Começa a 0 antes de fazer fork!
    nthreads = 0;

    mainpid = getpid();

    printf("\nEntering thread %d\n\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());

    //assim nao temos que usar mux mais abaixo quando fazemos uso destes valores na entrada da funcao
    pthread_mutex_lock(&processofilhomux);
    processofilho++;
    int localprocessofilho = processofilho;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&processofilhomux);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&processopaimux);
    processopai++;
    int localprocessopai = processopai; 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&processopaimux);

    fork_id=fork();
    if (fork_id==-1)
    {
        perror("Erro a criar filho:");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(fork_id==0)
    {
        if(signal(SIGUSR1, func_forcereadconfig) == SIG_ERR)
            printf("Erro no sinal SIGUSR1");
        if(signal(SIGINT, func_forcedsigint) == SIG_ERR)
            printf("Erro no sinal SIGINT");

        /***********************************************************************
        * Codigo do Filho
        * Espera clientes e cria uma thread para cada um.
        * Sempre que um cliente é criado, envia uma mensagem para o pai com o numero de clientes activos.
        * Sempre que um cliente é terminado, envia uma mensagem para o pai com o numero de clientes activos.
        *************************************************************************/

        int i, active_n=0;
        char address[BUFFSIZE];
        int msgsock;

        char nbuffer[50];

        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

        thread_s threadtable[MAXCLIENTSPERFORK];
        int a;
        for(a=0;a<MAXCLIENTSPERFORK;a++)
        {
            threadtable[a].thread = 0;
            threadtable[a].active = false;
            threadtable[a].t_buffer = NULL;
        }

        // Tempo inicial
        // Se passado X segundos nao existirem pedidos, o fork sai (desde que nao seja a primeiro child)
        struct timeval begin, now;
        gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);

        int timeout = 3;
        double timediff;

        while(cicle)
        {
            gettimeofday(&now , NULL);

            // Tempo que passou desde que iniciamos o timer
            timediff = (now.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) + 1e-6 * (now.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec);

            //printf("\nServer (2) Socket: %d\n", pstruct.recsock);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&nthreadsmux);

            if(localprocessofilho == 2)
            {
                printf("\n[%d] - Tempo que passou: %lf - %d\n", localprocessofilho, timediff, nthreads);
            }

            // Condicoes para execuçao:
            // - nthreads = 0 e timeout < timediff (queremos tentar ate existir um timeout)
            // - nthreads < MAXCLIENTSPERFORK mas maior que zero
            // - nthreads < MAXCLIENTSPERFORK e processo filho é o primeiro (corre sempre)
            if((nthreads == 0 && timeout > timediff) || nthreads < MAXCLIENTSPERFORK && nthreads > 0 || (nthreads < MAXCLIENTSPERFORK && localprocessofilho == 1))
            {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&nthreadsmux);

                // Espera um cliente
                printf("\tProcesso %d espera de clientes\n", localprocessofilho);
                if((msgsock = espera_pedido(pstruct.recsock, address)) < 0)
                    continue;

                pthread_mutex_lock(&athreadmux);

                // Figure out our thread number
                int a;
                for(a=0;a<MAXCLIENTSPERFORK;a++)
                {
                    if(threadtable[a].active == false)
                    {
                        if(threadtable[a].thread != 0)
                            pthread_join(threadtable[a].thread, NULL); // Temos que garantir que acaba...antes de a usar
                        break;
                    }
                }

                threadtable[a].t_buffer = malloc(sizeof(thread_buffer));
                if(threadtable[a].t_buffer == NULL)
                {
                    perror("\nErro (0) ao alocar estrutura config:");
                    exit(-1);
                }

                threadtable[a].t_buffer->msg = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFSIZE);
                if(threadtable[a].t_buffer->msg == NULL)
                {
                    perror("\nErro (0) ao alocar estrutura config:");
                    exit(-1);
                }

                sprintf(threadtable[a].t_buffer->msg, "%s", address);

                threadtable[a].t_buffer->sock = msgsock;
                threadtable[a].t_buffer->conf = conf;
                threadtable[a].active = true;

                // localtime é Non-threadsafe portanto temos que correr fora das threads criadas para cada pedido
                time_t timer = time(NULL);
                threadtable[a].t_buffer->t = *localtime(&timer);
                threadtable[a].t_buffer->timer = timer;

                // Cria nova threads
                if (pthread_create(&threadtable[a].thread, &attr, thread_func_pedido, (void*)&threadtable[a]) != 0)
                {
                    printf("\n\nERROR: %d", errno);
                    perror("Erro a criar thread: ");
                    close(msgsock);
                    free(threadtable[a].t_buffer);

                    printf("\n\n\n");
                    sleep(10);

                    continue;
                }

                pthread_mutex_unlock(&athreadmux);


                pthread_mutex_lock(&nthreadsmux);
                memset(nbuffer, '\0', sizeof(nbuffer));
                sprintf(nbuffer, "%d", nthreads);
                if(nthreads >= MAXCLIENTSPERFORK)
                {
                    printf("\nReached MAXCLIENTSPERFORK in Child %d\n", localprocessofilho);
                }
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&nthreadsmux);

                //printf("\nProcesso %d enviar para o pai: %s\n", localprocessofilho, nbuffer);
                write(fd[WRITE], nbuffer, (strlen(nbuffer)+1));

                // Reset ao timer
                gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
            }
            else if(nthreads == 0 && localprocessofilho > 1)
            {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&nthreadsmux);
                printf("\n00Reached 0 in Child %d\n", localprocessofilho);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&nthreadsmux);
            }
        }

        for(a=0;a<MAXCLIENTSPERFORK;a++)
        {
            if(threadtable[a].active != false)
            {
                pthread_join(threadtable[a].thread, NULL);
            }
        }

        printf("\nSAI FILHO\n\n");
        sleep(10);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        /***********************************************************************
        * Codigo do Pai
        * O pai apenas lê o que o filho envia pelo pipe.
        * O filho envia constantemente o numero de threads activas.
        * Quando n atinge zero, o processo mata-se a si próprio o pai espera pela sua morte.
        * Quando n atingoe MAXCLIENTSPERTHREAD o processo mete wantnewfork a TRUE.
        *************************************************************************/
        close(fd[WRITE]);

        char buf[10];
        pid_t result;
        int status;
        // Verifica o estado do child (se == 0 entao esta a correr)
        // Se este for o processo pai, nao é suposto sairmos, NUNCA (a menos que haja um sinal)
        while((result = waitpid(fork_id, &status, WNOHANG)) == 0 || localprocessopai == 1)
        {
            int retn = read(fd[READ], buf, 10);
            if(retn > 0)
            {
                int n = atoi(buf);
                //printf("\n--- PAI: %d |\n", n);

                if(n == 0 && localprocessopai > 1)
                {
                    int status = 0;
                    wait(&status);
                    printf("\n%d A sair...\n", localprocessopai);
                    break;
                }
                else if(n == MAXCLIENTSPERFORK)
                {
                    printf("\n\n\nQUEREMOS UM NOVO PROCESSO - %d!!!\n\n\n", n);
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&processomux);
                    wantnewfork = true;
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&processomux);
                }
            }
        }

        free(pst);

        // Está na hora de sair daqui
        int ret;
        printf("\n\n\n%d SAIR DA THREAD - %d - %d - %d\n\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(), localprocessopai, result, WIFEXITED(status));
        pthread_exit(&ret);
    }
}


void *thread_func_pedido(void * threadstruct)
{
    thread_s *tstmp = (thread_s*)threadstruct;
    thread_buffer t = *(*tstmp).t_buffer;

    char buffer[BUFSIZE];

    char ver;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&nthreadsmux);
    nthreads++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&nthreadsmux);

    /*Leitura do Pedido*/
    int totalread;
    if((totalread = recv(t.sock, buffer, BUFSIZE,0)) <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nTotal read: %d\n", totalread);
        perror("Erro lendo a request: ");

        wait(10);

        close(t.sock);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&nthreadsmux);
        if(nthreads > 0)
            nthreads--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&nthreadsmux);

        int ret;
        pthread_exit(&ret);
    }

    req_data pedido;
    pedido = init_data();

    /* Processamento do Pedido */
    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        pedido.errorcode=400;
    }
    else
    {
        pedido.request = convert_get(buffer,&pedido.errorcode,&ver);

        if(pedido.errorcode==200)
        {
            if(special_request(t.sock, pedido.request,ver) == false)
            {
                pedido.errorcode = imprime_ficheiro(t.sock, pedido.request, ver, t.conf->httpdocs, t.conf->cgibin);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pedido.errorcode != 200)
    {
        imprime_erro(t.sock, pedido.errorcode, ver, pedido.request);
    }

    /*--- Armazenamento do Pedido ---*/
    pedido = gen_data(pedido.errorcode, (char*)t.msg, pedido.request, tstmp->t_buffer->t, tstmp->t_buffer->timer);

    pthread_mutex_lock( &mux );
    FILE* statfile = (FILE*) stat_init();
    stat_armazena_req(pedido,statfile);
    fclose(statfile);
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mux );

    pedido=free_data(pedido);

    //printf("\nClosing socket %d\n", t.sock);
    close(t.sock);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&nthreadsmux);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&processofilhomux);
    if(nthreads > 0)
        nthreads--;
    //printf("\n [%d] nthreads reduced to %d\n",processofilho, nthreads);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&processofilhomux);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&nthreadsmux);

    // Free the thread buffer, we're going to realloc it later
    free(tstmp->t_buffer->msg);
    free(tstmp->t_buffer);
    tstmp->t_buffer = NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&athreadmux);
    tstmp->active = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&athreadmux);

    int ret;
    pthread_exit(&ret);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){


    // Mascara de Sinais 
    if(signal(SIGTERM, func_sigint) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("Erro no sinal SIGCONT");

    if(signal(SIGINT, func_sigint) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("Erro no sinal SIGINT");

    if(signal(SIGUSR1, func_readconfig) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("Erro no sinal SIGUSR1");


    // Socket
    sock = cria_socket(PORT);

    conf = read_config("./www.config");
    if(conf == NULL)
    {
        conf = (config*)malloc(sizeof(config));
        if(conf == NULL)
        {
            perror("\nErro (2) ao alocar estrutura config:");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // Set defaults
        sprintf(conf->httpdocs, DOCUMENT_ROOT);
        sprintf(conf->cgibin, CGI_ROOT);
    }

    /*
        Inicialmente é criado um processo que tratará de X threads/clientes
        Após cada cliente ser tratado, a respectiva thread é destruída
        Depois, caso a lista de threads esteja vazia, o processo mata-se a si próprio, informado o pai do sucedido.
        Só é criado um novo processo caso não existam processos livres (i.e. se houver muitos clientes concorrentes)
        O processo pai cria uma thread para cada processo filho criado,
        de forma a que estas consigam interagir com o mesmo através de um pipe
    */
    while (cicle)
    {
        //Aparentemente o ultimo processo ficou cheio, portanto temos que criar um novo
        pthread_mutex_lock(&processomux);
        if(wantnewfork)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&processomux);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&processopaimux);
            printf("\n-----------PROCESSO NUM: %d\n", processopai+1);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&processopaimux);

            pthread_t forkthread;
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);


            process_struct *pstruct = malloc(sizeof(process_struct));
            if(pstruct == NULL)
            {
                perror("\nErro (0) ao alocar estrutura config:");
                exit(-1);
            }

            pstruct->recsock = sock;
            pstruct->conf = conf;

            //printf("\nServer (1) Socket: %d\n", pstruct->recsock);

            if (pthread_create(&forkthread, &attr, gere_processo, (void *)pstruct) != 0)
            {
                perror("Erro a criar thread gere_processo: ");
                exit(-1);
            }

            pthread_mutex_lock(&processomux);
            wantnewfork = false;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&processomux);
        }
        else
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&processomux);

        usleep(10000);
    }

    close(sock);
    free(conf);

    printf("Sai Pai\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

I have a global variable named sock which holds the fd. The pstruct also has a member called revsock which has the same value as sock.

Apparently recsock is what gets changed (valgrind doesn't complain) but sock remains unchanged.

free(pst) might be the cause of it - though I'm unsure why it executes (it shouldn't for the main process - but that would explain the random exits and that would cause the bad file descriptor issue for random exits on threads which are not the 2nd thread).

I don't understand why free(pst) would cause this though...the child should have its own pst structure as well. But if I comment free(pst) I no longer have bad file descriptor issues.
Still, free(pst) should be there, it's the "random thread exiting" that's causing it to run when it shouldn't.

Comment: You're not using the return value from recv to determine how many bytes were read.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm using the return value of recv and printing it to the screen.

Comment: recv is not guaranteed to read BUFSZ bytes, so you need to use its return value for writes and possibly future reads.  If recv only gets 1024 bytes while BUFSZ is 4096 and you try to write BUFSZ bytes from the buffer, you will get old data mixed in.

Comment: I see you're only using `errno` once. That would hinder inspectability into the situation

Comment: Also, `if (buffer == NULL)` is wrong. The buffer is never `NULL`

Comment: @technosaurus I don't understand what you mean sorry. I read from the socket - if nothing is read, the socket is closed and the connection terminated (thread exits). If we read something, we continue.

Comment: @mnunberg yeap noticed that thanks but that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @mnunberg "I see you're only using errno once. That would hinder inspectability into the situation" - care to elaborate please?

Comment: If any socket call fails, you'd want to check errno immediately: `int errno_save; rv = recv(...); if (rv < 0) { errno_save = errno; printf("Got an error: %s\n", strerror(errno));`

Comment: Thanks, I've included that now. I'd also like to note that I'm getting (always) the issue of "auto thread exit" when sending 400 concurrents users and 10000 connections.

Answer (score 1):

If the integer that represents the socket's file descriptor changes suddenly, and your program didn't intentionally change it, then you have one of two bugs:

- You're using threads and you aren't locking your thread's access to shared memory. This might lead to things like using a pointer before it is set to a value. If that pointer is to memory with the fd in it, that could overwrite it.
- You have a buffer overflow. Somewhere, your program is writing bad data into the memory that holds the file descriptor.

To solve the problem I recommend using a debugger and a hardware watchpoint to tell you when the value of the file descriptor changes.

Comment: I am using valgrind (and helgrind) and I have no overflows. I have tracked down the issue to a line which takes care of the connection. It seems write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char)); is crashing (or the equivelent dprintf) (where I write OK\n etc)

Comment: I've found the crash issue here: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1333297-dprintf-vdprintf-can-cause-fork-to-fail-child-process-crash but it's related to dprintf which I Have replaced by write meanwhile as you can see in my example in the comment above